# Specific Decision Rule from Decision Tree Classifier Pipeline With Vectorizing and Feature Union

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree, text-classification, scikit-learn-pipeline

In order to get the specific rules applied to a trained sample on a decision tree classifier, we need to use the decision_path method: `decision_path(X[, check_input])`.

Now, working on a short text classification model, I have pipelined a feature union on the vectorization of text features and applied gridsearch to find an optimized model as shown in the code below.

1. This makes it difficult to call the X features into the `decision_path` method as I keep getting errors
2. Also I would finally have sought to illustrate the path with the text features instead of the numeric vectorized features...

```
data, target = df['doc_text'], target_column
data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test, indices_train, indices_test  = train_test_split(
    data, target, df.index, random_state=0)

#combine words an character grams features
vectorizer = FeatureUnion([
    ('word_vectorizer',  TfidfVectorizer(
    sublinear_tf=True,
    min_df=2,
    #strip_accents='unicode',
    #encoding='latin-1'
    analyzer='word',
    #token_pattern=r'\w{1,}',
    ngram_range=(2,5),
    norm='l2')),
    #dtype = np.float32, #da error
    #max_features = 6000)),

    ('char_vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(
    sublinear_tf=True,
    min_df=5,
    stop_words='english',
    strip_accents='unicode',
    analyzer='char',
    ngram_range=(2, 5),
    norm='l2',
    #dtype=np.float32,
    max_features = 8000))
])

pipelinedt= Pipeline([
        ("tfidf", vectorizer),
        ("clfdt", DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy",max_depth=7)),
])

tree_para ={  "clfdt__max_depth": (7,25,100),
              "clfdt__min_samples_leaf": (1,5,10),
              "tfidf__word_vectorizer__max_df": (0.5, 0.75),
              "tfidf__word_vectorizer__min_df": (2,),
              "tfidf__char_vectorizer__max_df": (0.5, 0.75),
              "tfidf__char_vectorizer__min_df": (3,),
              "tfidf__char_vectorizer__use_idf": (True, False),
              "tfidf__word_vectorizer__use_idf": (True, False),
              "tfidf__word_vectorizer__ngram_range": ((1, 2), (2, 4), ),
              "tfidf__char_vectorizer__ngram_range": ((4, 5),),
} 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dt = GridSearchCV(pipelinedt, tree_para, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
    dt.fit(data_train, target_train)

    best_clf= dt.best_estimator_
    best_score= dt.best_score_ 
    best_parameters = dt.best_estimator_.get_params()

    print ("Best-clf es",best_clf)
    print ("Best-score es",best_score)
    print("Best Parameters: \n{}\n".format(dt.best_params_))

    from sklearn import tree

    feature = dt.best_estimator_.named_steps['clfdt'].tree_.feature
    threshold = dt.best_estimator_.named_steps['clfdt'].tree_.threshold
    node_indicator = dt.best_estimator_.named_steps['clfdt'].decision_path(pipelinedt.named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names_out())

    sample_id = 6108

    node_index = node_indicator.indices[
        node_indicator.indptr[sample_id] : node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]
    ]

    print("Rules used to predict sample {id}:\n".format(id=sample_id))
    for node_id in node_index:
        # continue to the next node if it is a leaf node
        if leaf_id[sample_id] == node_id:
            continue

        # check if value of the split feature for sample 0 is below threshold
        if data_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]:
            threshold_sign = "<="
        else:
            threshold_sign = ">"

        print(
            "decision node {node} : (X_test[{sample}, {feature}] = {value}) "
            "{inequality} {threshold})".format(
                node=node_id,
                sample=sample_id,
                feature=feature[node_id],
                value=data_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]],
                inequality=threshold_sign,
                threshold=threshold[node_id],
            )
        )
```

I have tried playing with the node_indicator variable on many alternatives without success as I have trouble calling the features which have been vectorized and pipelined.

Actually, I would clearly be much interested after this works to also print out the decision tree path to the chosen sample using the text features and not the vectorized ones.

Anybody can help how to tackle this.
The last error I got on my above trial where I desperately tried the method `.get_feature_names_out()` is :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13648/4239244359.py in <module>
      9 threshold = dt.best_estimator_.named_steps['clfdt'].tree_.threshold
     10 
---> 11 node_indicator = dt.best_estimator_.named_steps['clfdt'].decision_path(pipelinedt.named_steps['tfidf'].get_feature_names_out()[2])
     12 #node_indicator = dt.best_estimator_.named_steps['clfdt'].decision_path(pipelinedt.named_steps['tfidf'].fit_transform(data_test))
     13 #pipe['tfid'].idf_

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in decision_path(self, X, check_input)
    542             indicates that the samples goes through the nodes.
    543         """
--> 544         X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
    545         return self.tree_.decision_path(X)
    546 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    431         """Validate the training data on predict (probabilities)."""
    432         if check_input:
--> 433             X = self._validate_data(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr", reset=False)
    434             if issparse(X) and (
    435                 X.indices.dtype != np.intc or X.indptr.dtype != np.intc

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    559             raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    560         elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 561             X = check_array(X, **check_params)
    562             out = X
    563         elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    736                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    737                 else:
--> 738                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    739             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    740                 raise ValueError(

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'word_vectorizer__acpt is'
```

Comment: To go from numerical features (output of TDifdvectorizer) back to words (input), use inverse_transform()

Comment: And you must transform your input data using transform() of TDifdvectorizer before passing to the decision_path

Comment: I believe this is already taken care of by the pipeline... because of it its also harder to retrieve the details on the path for only one sample.

Comment: Normally for fit/predict etc yes. But then you need to call decision_path on the pipeline as well (not on the step). And I do not think that is supported? In which case you have to do the "pipelining" yourself.

Comment: Thank you Jon... that indeed it is what a was thinking... I thought there would be a work around still using the pipeline... if not i will indeed need to do the pipelining flow myself out of the pipeline method as you say.